# I couldn't install rllab python package?

Tags: python, anaconda

I try to install rllab python package but I couldn't.
this error showed after pip install Rllab command:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Rllab (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Rllab
what should I do?
I use window10 and also use anaconda3

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: windows10 and also anaconda 3

Comment: can you please add all the steps you took to install Rllab?

Comment: I only use "pip install rllab" and received this comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rllab (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for rllab then I try this code in anaconda: conda env create -f environment.yml and recieved this: Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org

SpecNotFound: Can't process without a name

Comment: yes from Anaconda website...I think, I can not perform the installation process correctly...

Comment: try following: 1-  conda create -n rllab python=3.5 (pick your version)           2-  activate rllab   3- pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade rllab

Comment: thank you I copied rllab in my folder

Comment: Is everything working now?

Comment: RLLAB is ok now! but I can't run my code